# How to specify a custom role in MongoDB Atlas for collections across databases?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

When creating a role in MongoDB you can specify a resource as a collection across all databases by leaving the database blank (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/resource-document/#specify-collections-across-databases-as-resource), i.e.

```
{ db: "", collection: "my-collection" }
```

When creating a custom role in MongoDB Atlas, the equivalent functionality does not seem to be available, as database name is required.

Is this something that can be done in MongoDB Atlas?